# Converting Android apps to ios apps

Tags: j2objc

I developed an Android app which I want to convert it to ios app.
I have seen that J2OBJC helps in converting java code to C code.

Can anyone please help me out how to do that.
And the other doubt I have is : Using J2OBJC we can just only convert businness logic. So what about UI part?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sindhu

Answer (score 1):

The app's UI is rewritten, using iOS frameworks such as UIKit. j2objc is focused on making it easier to ship "big apps", apps that have a lot of shared code between different platforms. If your app doesn't have a lot of shared, non-UI code, then j2objc is not your best option.